# Checking domains HSTS status

Tags: chrome, hsts

The Google Chrome browser offers a quick way to check a domain's HSTS (HTTP Strict Transport Security) status via the page `chrome://net-internals/#hsts` (section *Query domain*).

The query result looks e.g. like this:

```
Found:
domain: owasp.org
static_upgrade_mode: UNKNOWN
static_sts_include_subdomains: 
static_pkp_include_subdomains: 
static_sts_observed: 
static_pkp_observed: 
static_spki_hashes: 
dynamic_upgrade_mode: STRICT
dynamic_sts_include_subdomains: false
dynamic_pkp_include_subdomains: false
dynamic_sts_observed: 1409173001.03746
dynamic_pkp_observed: 1409173001.03746
dynamic_spki_hashes:
```

What do these lines mean? Is the HSTS mode enabled or not? What is the difference between the `dynamic_` and `static_` entries of the result?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If either of the `static_upgrade_mode:` or the `dynamic_upgrade_mode:` lines are set to `STRICT` then HSTS is enabled.

## Dynamic

`Dynamic` means that the browser has been instructed to enable HSTS by an HTTP response header (served over TLS) similar to the following:

`Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=157680000; includeSubDomains;`

This is vulnerable to an attack whereby the very first time the browser requests the domain with `http://` (not `https://`) an adversary intercepts the communication.

## Static

In order to overcome this weakness we have the `static` mode which allows for hard-coding HSTS records directly into the browser's source. The header is changed to indicate the administrator's intention:

`Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=157680000; includeSubDomains; preload`

Note the inclusion of `preload` at the end. The domain is then [submitted](https://hstspreload.org/) for review. If approved then it is added to [the Chromium list](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/net/+/master/http/transport_security_state_static.json) which is also included in the Firefox, Safari, and IE 11+Edge lists.

Answer (score 4):

When you are querying to `chrome://net-internals/#hsts` then it queries only the stored HSTS sites that you have visited using chrome.
The part `static_` and `dynamic_` shows the methods to enable STS for the communication.

The result shows there is no `static` methods defined only `dynamic` methods are there. `pop` and `sts` in the result stand for *public-key-pinning* and *strict transport security* repectively. So `dynamic_pkp_observed` and `dynamic_sts_obeserved` is the time for STS which is enabled for the doamin. The STS is allowed on that domain but not for subdomains.

It would be better to use "curl" for checking the sts.
For example:
`curl -siL "owasp.org"  | grep "Strict"`  (-L to redirect to https)

If the domain is configured to use STS then in the server response you will see the header `Strict-Transport-Security: max-age =`*value*
That is why I'm gripping for `Strict`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer so far. I feel still somehow dumb (as if everybody would understand the topic but me), but I'll ask the questions anyway: What is the difference between dynamic and static? What does the upgrade modes (UNKNOWN, STRICT, OPPORTUNISTIC) again mean? I have tried playing with curl in my cygwin. I could never see the HSTS header attribute in any domain I have tried (google, gmail, owasp, ...). What am I doing wrong? BTW. Any good books on this topic?

Comment: Static means the server will always communicate over hsts it doesn't require client to configure your browser to use hsts for that page. In the other hand dynamic means if the user is requesting that page over hsts. Static unknown means the server doesn't support hsts by itself. Strict means the server will use hsts for all the communications.

Comment: So why do I *not see* the `Strict-Transport-Security: max-age =value` when I run that curl above? If HSTS is critical, then I'd expect OWASP to implement it, right? Instead I seem to be looking at an Apache/Nginx 301 Redirect to the HTTPS domain. Is the `Strict-Transport-Security` header no longer how it works 2 years after this answer?

Comment: Should be curl -si "h t t p s://owasp.org"  | grep "Strict", because the header is only sent on https.

The request to http should include a redirect to https.

curl -siL owasp.org|grep "Strict" will work, because L makes curl follow this redirect.

Answer (score 1):

`static` means browser (in this case Chrome) [Preloaded HSTS sites](https://www.chromium.org/hsts)
`dynamic` means sites that got picked up "on the go" or added [manually](http://chrome://net-internals/#hsts)

`pkp` stands for [Public](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Public_Key_Pinning) [Key Pinning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Public_Key_Pinning), which is since Chrome 69 [deprecated](https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5903385005916160)
`spki_hashes` stands for [SubjectPublicKeyInfo hashes](https://raymii.org/s/articles/HTTP_Public_Key_Pinning_Extension_HPKP.html#SPKI_Fingerprint_-_Theory)

`_include_subdomains` mean whether to include subdomains in the request
`_observed` is the [UNIX time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) on which the browser first observed the request
`_expiry` is the [UNIX time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) on which the browser will forget the request